# Creating a single source jar for a multi-module gradle project

Tags: gradle, build, multi-module, build-system

I have a multi-module gradle project setup like this:

```
Module A (Parent)
-build.gradle
-settings.gradle
+Module B
--src
---main
----java
----kotlin
--build.gradle
+Module C
--src
---main
----java
----kotlin
--build.gradle
```

In this instance, Module B has a compile time dependency on Module C.

I want to create a sources jar including the sources from all sub-projects to publish to my repository.

In single module builds I have added the following to my project, but adding it to all subprojects  does not result in the collection of source sets in the sources jar produced:

```
sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.kotlin
    from sourceSets.main.java
    archiveClassifier = 'sources'
}
```

How can I do this? ShadowJar works but unfortunately does not provide the option to create a sources jar as far as I know.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to have a single sources jar?

Comment: In our use case the multi-module project functions as a library depended upon by an application that lives elsewhere. In practice there are more sub-modules which depend on Module C than in my example, and at the moment we want to be able to depend on them all from the other application. The sub-modules themselves are all quite lightweight so we want to avoid creating a collection of repositories to house them if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found a solution - deploy the sub-modules as independent sources jar and include them on an individual basis.

For example, in each sub-module:

```
sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.kotlin
    from sourceSets.main.java
    archiveClassifier = 'sources'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = rootProject.group
            artifactId = "$rootProject.name-$project.name"
            version = rootProject.project.version
            from components.java
            artifact sourcesJar
        }
    }
```